# Using Azure VPN Gateway to access an external Database through a whitelisted public IP

Tags: azure, networking, vpn

I'm fairly new the Networking side of Azure, so thanks for taking you time to respond.

My use case is the following:

We have an external Database resource that requires us to provide one(or more) public IPs for whitelisting whilst they provide us with an IP to access the database (plus login data).

For this, our thought was to create a Virtual Network with a VPN Gateway to allow us to provide a single Public IP address which should allow everyone connected to the VPN (with internal private addresses) to access this resource.

My questions are the following:

Is this a valid use case?
If so, would providing the public IP of the VPN Gateway for whitelisting be enough to allow us to connect to that resource or is there anything else we need to do to achieve this(like a tunnel)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you have a Database on Azure and you are trying to connect to it using an Azure Site-Site VPN for your onprem users. If this is scenario, then this is a valid use case, but I think you will need to provision a private endpoint connectivity to your Database in order to establish connectivity. Following will be the high level steps required.

1. Procure a Site-Site or Point-Site VPN
2. [Establish Private endpoint
   connectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-sql-portal) for your database.
3. Create a [DNS configuration for
   you Azure Private Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns)